# Ajax toolkit error

Tags: custom-button, ajax-toolkit

I am getting below error when clicking on Cls (custom detail button) on Custom object record.

> faultcode:soapenv:Client,faultString:"6/3/2015" is not a valid value for type xsd:date

[image]

Below is the custom button code.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var newRecords = [];

var ib = new sforce.SObject("Disc__c"); 
ib.id = '{!Disc__c.Id}';
ib.Date_Closed__c = '{!TODAY()}';
alert(ib.Date_Closed__c);
ib.Status__c = 'Complete';
newRecords.push(ib);

result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 


window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.Here is the solution

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var newRecords = [];

var ib = new sforce.SObject("Disc__c"); 
ib.id = '{!Disc__c.Id}';
var today = new Date();
ib.Date_Closed__c = fixDate(today);
ib.Status__c = 'Complete';
newRecords.push(ib);

result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 


window.location.reload();



function fixTime(time){
    if(time < 10) {time = "0" + time};
    return time;
}

function fixDate(date){
  var Month = fixTime(date.getMonth() + 1);
  var Day = fixTime(date.getDate());
  var UTC = date.toUTCString();
  var Time = UTC.substring(UTC.indexOf(':')-2, UTC.indexOf(':')+6);
  var Minutes = fixTime(date.getMinutes());
  var Seconds = fixTime(date.getSeconds());
  return date.getFullYear() + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + "T" + Time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with below snippet:

```
1. ib.Date_Closed__c = {!Today}
```

or, if you want to add days

```
2. ib.Date_Closed__c = new Date(start.setDate(start.getDate() + 30));
```

Thanks!